# SUM in the last row "WITH ROLLUP" position?

Tags: sql, ms-access, rollup

I want the sum of "Anzahl" (translated => "Count") in the last row of the query. I already used "WITH ROLLUP" before, however in this case I can't figure out where to put it.

There are some calculations made in the code. If you have any suggestions how to create a smarter query please let me know.

````
   (SELECT SUM(XA.Anzahl)
   FROM tbl_Transaktion XA
   WHERE XA.TeileNr = B.TeileNR and
                XA.Zustand = 1)
 -
   (SELECT SUM(XC.Stueckzahl_Prod)
   FROM tbl_Produktion XC
   WHERE XC.TeileNr = B.TeileNR) AS Rohteile, 



   (SELECT SUM(XD.Stueckzahl_Prod)
   FROM tbl_Produktion XD
   WHERE XD.TeileNr = B.TeileNR) AS Fertigteile, 


   
   (SELECT SUM(XE.Anzahl)
   FROM tbl_Transaktion XE
   WHERE XE.TeileNr = B.TeileNR and
                XE.Zustand = 4)
-
  (SELECT SUM(XF.Anzahl)
   FROM tbl_Transaktion XF
   WHERE XF.TeileNr = B.TeileNR and
                XF.Zustand = 6) AS Gesperrt, 



   (SELECT MAX(XF.Kommentar)
   FROM tbl_Transaktion XF
   WHERE XF.TeileNr = B.TeileNR and
                XF.Zustand = 6) AS Kommentar, 



  (SELECT SUM(YA.Anzahl)
   FROM tbl_Transaktion YA
   WHERE YA.TeileNr = B.TeileNR and
                YA.Zustand = 1) 
 -
  (SELECT SUM(YC.Stueckzahl_Prod)
   FROM tbl_Produktion YC
   WHERE YC.TeileNr = B.TeileNR) 
+
  (SELECT SUM(YD.Stueckzahl_Prod)
   FROM tbl_Produktion YD
   WHERE YD.TeileNr = B.TeileNR)
+
  (SELECT SUM(YE.Anzahl)
   FROM tbl_Transaktion YE
   WHERE YE.TeileNr = B.TeileNR and
                YE.Zustand = 4)
-
  (SELECT SUM(YF.Anzahl)
   FROM tbl_Transaktion YF
   WHERE YF.TeileNr = B.TeileNR and
                YF.Zustand = 6) AS Gesamt


FROM tbl_TeileNr AS A INNER JOIN tbl_Transaktion AS B ON A.TeileNr = B.TeileNr
WHERE Gesperrt = false AND Produktgruppe = 1
GROUP BY B.TeileNr
ORDER BY B.TeileNr;```
````

Comment: Edit tags for the database used.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan sorry for not mentioning. The project is based on a 2021 MS Access database (MS SQL).

Comment: No problem :).. As much as I know Ms aCcess doesn't have `ROLL UP` clause, and `UNION ALL` might be used as an alternative even if it's not a practical manner. Btw, correlated subqueries not needed, but use like `.... MAX(CASE WHEN XF.Zustand = 6 THEN XA.Anzahl END) AS Kommentar....` and so on...